# When I call this API I get result via jQuery but not via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I call this API then I will get `invalid certificate`.

How to resolve this issue?

```
 string res = string.Empty;
 string str = context.Request["params"].ToString();

 string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
 {
   login = "aaa",
   password = "ssss",
   command = "ssl_decoder",
   ssl_certificate = str
 });

 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
    .Create("https://api.sslguru.com?params="+str.Normalize());

 httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
 httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

 using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
 {
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
      res = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
 }

 return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable cookies in the request, some api demands it (paypal for say):

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
yourWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `invalid certificate` because your request is building an SSL connection but you actually connet to the non-ssl port 80. The servers returns an usual html page were the HttpWebRequest is waiting for an SSL handshake. And that gives the certificate eror.

When you use SSL be explict  by using the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z9y1as%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build your Uri to point to serverport that has SSL configured.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
    .Create(new UriBuilder("https", 
                           "api.sslguru.com", 
                            443, /* THE PORT THAT IS CONFIGURED FOR TLS/SSL */
                            "", 
                            "?params="+str.Normalize()).Uri);
```

Or if you are more of a quick-fix type of developer:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
    .Create("https://api.sslguru.com:443?params="+str.Normalize());
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work just the same instead of using the UriBuilder?
`https://api.sslguru.com:443/blablabla`